# What is the significance of this horned creature that appears sometimes in Bejeweled Blitz?

Tags: bejeweled-blitz

Sometimes when I'm playing Bejeweled Blitz on Facebook, I notice this deer/elk thing show up on the left side of the screen:

[image: Bejeweled Blitz screen]

It's not there when the game starts (at least I've never noticed it), and I can't figure out if it has any effect on gameplay or what triggers it showing up. Maybe it's random and has no meaning! Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://forums.popcap.com/showthread.php?626-stag&s=638eeb048932cfe891e8da45ccb9d23b&p=2901&viewfull=1#post2901

According to someone at PopCap:

> The "stag" in the background that appears has no other significance
>   other than one of our artists created a rather cool Autumnal scene to
>   use for the game that has a sort of mystical quality to it. Everytime
>   you hit a multipier, a new part of the scene is added. Kind of cool,
>   huh?

So no, it has no meaning.

Comment: Horacio the Stag. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to only appear when you reach 4 times multiplier, as you increase in multipliers it disappears and the scenery changes, I have noticed it change to a purplish color